# ubuntu 12.04LTS libvirt no conenction driver available

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, xen

I am trying to setup a vm using xen under ubuntu 12.04LTS. I have installed the default libvirt version but I have some errors when trying to run:

```
$ virsh -c <uri> list
```

the errors are:

```
error: no connection driver available for No connection for URI xen:///
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
```

I have found [this](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Failed_to_connect_to_the_hypervisor#No_connection_driver_available) information, but it does not really help me as my libvirt isn't compiled from sources.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the libvirt daemon was not started.

```
sudo start libvirt-bin
```

did the trick. 
Also check your /etc/default/libvirt-bin if start_libvirtd is set to "yes"

if it is you'll get additional info in the log 
/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log

finally if not root you user needs to be in the libvirt group and possibly in the kvm group. Once added you'll at least need to logoff/logon to take this new membership into account.